# Sharepoint Client context (client Object Model) cant load more than 500 records or more

Tags: development, client-object-model, limitations

is here any limitation about read the records from any lists in sharepoint?

my codes are default that downloaded from msdn:

```
    string siteUrl = SharePointAddressURL;

    ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(SharePointAddressURL);
    SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(TargetListName);

    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
        "<Value Type='Number'>10</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>500</RowLimit></View>";
    ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.Load(collListItem);

    try
    {
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = e1.Message;

        throw;
    }
```

is there **RowLimit** limitation?

this app works very good but newer records that their ID greater that about 500 does not appear

very strange for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added the <RowLimit>500</RowLimit> yourself in the ViewXml Property - so only 500 items will be returned. 
AFAIK there is no limit, but you could run into a timeout or memory limit on your client.

I would recommend you the free CAMLDesigner (http://sharepoint.biwug.be/SitePages/Caml_Designer.aspx) - there you can create your caml and check the results in a nice GUI.

Comment: when i'm starting programming this app copy and paste from msdn and because i don't know anything about this CAML never have enough attention to it. this is very joky for me that why i haven't seen it . but CAML DESIGNER that you recommend is very simple and useful for teaching and learning. thanks. so thanks.